# How to import a function exported using this given export construct?

Tags: typescript, highlight, highlight.js, typescript1.6, tsd

DefinitelyTyped has a definition for Highlight.js which defines and exports a module like so:

```
declare module "highlight.js"
{
    module hljs
    {
        export function highlight(
            name: string,
            value: string,
            ignore_illegals?: boolean,
            continuation?: boolean) : IHighlightResult;
        ...
    }
    export = hljs;
}
```

In a given typescript file, I'm attempting to import the `hljs` object so I can call the `highlight` function on it, like so:

```
/// <reference path="../../tsd_typings/highlightjs/highlightjs.d.ts" />

import {hljs} from 'highlight.js';

...

hljs.highlightBlock(block);
```

But it fails saying that `error TS2305: Module '"highlight.js"' has no exported member 'hljs'.`

What is the proper way to import this object so I can compile my TS files without erros and warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The import statement should be:

```
import * as hljs from 'highlight.js';
```

That is the equivalent of:

```
import hljs = require('highlight.js');
```

and will import the entire module as `hljs`.